# Mysql showing all database when not assigned version 5.7.20

Tags: mysql, database

In my database MYSQL, Local user is sometimes able to access all Databases and able to edit it and some times able to access only single database (i.e) his assigned database.

Can anybody help why this abnormal behavior is happening in MySql 5.7.20

By this abnormal behavior some users are deliberately able to delete some tables in my databases.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Why don't you use 2 different users?

Comment: The same user from the same client configured in the same way? Sounds very unlikely. More likely the permissions are wrong